Analytical List Page - Quantity field is not summed
I created an OData service without a CDS view and added annotations to MPC_EXT->DEFINE:
I have one measure and five dimensions defined - like this:
 METHOD define.
    super->define( ).
    DATA(lo_entity_type) = model->get_entity_type( 'WeekValues' ).
    lo_entity_type->set_semantic( /iwbep/if_ana_odata_types=>gcs_ana_odata_semantic_value-query-aggregate ).

    DATA(lo_property) = lo_entity_type->get_property( 'NumberCount' ).
    DATA(lo_annotation) = lo_property->/iwbep/if_mgw_odata_annotatabl~create_annotation( /iwbep/if_mgw_med_odata_types=>gc_sap_namespace ).
    lo_annotation->add( iv_key = /iwbep/if_ana_odata_types=>gcs_ana_odata_annotation_key-aggregation_role iv_value = /iwbep/if_ana_odata_types=>gcs_ana_odata_annotation_value-measure-measure ).


    lo_property = lo_entity_type->get_property( 'GENERATED_ID' ).
    lo_annotation = lo_property->/iwbep/if_mgw_odata_annotatabl~create_annotation( /iwbep/if_mgw_med_odata_types=>gc_sap_namespace ).
    lo_annotation->add( iv_key = /iwbep/if_ana_odata_types=>gcs_ana_odata_annotation_key-aggregation_role iv_value = /iwbep/if_ana_odata_types=>gcs_ana_odata_annotation_value-dimension

The GENERATED_ID is not derived by SADL - because it didn't work. So I provided this unique field which is the only key in my entity set.
I build a simple app based on the analytical list page floor plan and tried to implement an interactive chart where NumberCount is the measure and Week is the dimension.
The result is as follows:

The field Menge is not aggregated, which might lead to the problem with the interactive chart.
I also tried to set
  METHOD if_sadl_gw_query_control~set_query_options.

    io_query_options->set_aggregation( VALUE #(
         ( element = 'NUMBERCOUNT' alias = 'NUMBERCOUNT' type = if_sadl_gw_query_options=>co_aggregation_type-sum ) ) ).


  ENDMETHOD.

But it seems that this method from SADL is not called. My google search:

Fiori Elements: Analytical table with SADL

Annotating and Extending Fiori Element Applications: List Report Part 1

Custom OData Service Design for Analytical List Page Application


And many more ...
This field is not summed up ... I believe it is related that the SADL method set_query_options is not called therefore the annotation for sum is not set.
Any suggestions!? If nothing helps, I have to switch to CDS view... But...
Cheers Sven
